# How can I know the Timezone of my Web site Host

Tags: timezone, web-hosting

I know this one is the weirdest of all weird questions I have asked till date. But I have a reason.

The problem is that I have a no of websites hosted in diff servers (I dont own these servers) and every website has some pages where I have to enter some execution date and time. The date/time I enter should be of the timezone in which my website's host server is running.

Just want to know if there is any good utility/website which can tell me the timezone/location of my web host if I provide the web site address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put on each of those servers your own "system" page that will display the current time.

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

And you will access it like: http://site-no-x.com/timecheck

Something like this. Simple and effective.

ADDED: Keep in mind also that web servers and database servers can also have different time settings. If a hosting company (theoretically) keeps the web server farm on East coast and has the database servers on West coast, you will see different dates returned by .NET's DateTime.Now and SQL's GETDATE().

Comment: Thats not a bad idea Mastermind - In fact I had thought about creating a dashboard web page which will hit a webservice endpoint (Timecheck.asmx) on each server and list each servers date time and timezone. But I have reserved it as a last resort hoping that the problem already has a solution on the net. I still have sufficient time to wait before I implement the dashboard thing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't likely to be possible, as timezones are set at the OS level. (i.e.: You'd need to check programatically on each server itself using your language of choice.)

As such, it might be easier in the long to fix the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't modify the code to have the thing use UTC?